# Are a dynamic number of CSS Grid columns possible with optional header or footer row

Tags: html, css, css-grid

With CSS Grid a dynamic number of columns is easy.

```css
.grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}
```

```html
// these .cells layout nicely
<div class="grid">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

But what about more complex layouts with a header and or footer?

```css
// doesnt work
.grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr, repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)), 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <header></header>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

This doesn't seem possible without starting a new grid by wrapping the cells in a container... Which is what I'm hoping to avoid by adopting grid here.

Also using template areas doesn't work because the point is that header and footer are optional.

Is this dynamic nature possible with CSS Grid?

**UPDATE**
This doesn't seem to be possible.
I used JS to change a CSS custom property to update the grid columns.

**ANSWER**
The pen by Paulie_D does not solve anything but rather demonstrates the issue.

The answer is that this is not possible with CSS Grid. In fact almost all circumstances we need to specify columns. Which to my earlier point waters down the benefits of using grid IMO.

```
// HTML
<div class="grid">
    <header></header>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <footer></footer>
</div>

// CSS
.grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
header,footer {
    grid-span: 1 / -1;
}
```

Comment: the codepen provided by Paulie doesn't solve your issue (https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rNVZNgp) ? it seems the case for me. If not update your question to make it clear

Comment: *The answer is that this is not possible with CSS Grid. In fact almost all circumstances we need to specify columns. Which to my earlier point waters down the benefits of using grid IMO* --> this doesn't make sense. CSS grid provide properties to be used with the Grid container AND the grid items and that code demonstrate that it's possible with CSS grid. You cannot define all the behaviors of grid item inside the grid container.

Comment: Exactly. So it would be just as easy to use flex layout and define rules for the header and footer (if they exist) which is what I have to do with grid layout.

Comment: Wait for browsers to implement subgrid

Comment: @PraveenPuglia that is the best answer here!

Comment: @PraveenPuglia how can you solve this using subgrid without explicitely specifying the position for each element and without adding an extra wrapper? Note that subgrid doesn't apply here because the element are inside the same parent so all are in the same grid already

Answer (score 4):

I'm note sure if I understand your problem, let me see:

If you want a full width header/footer and, in between, a 3 column grid, just set the `<header>` and `<footer>` `grid-column` property to `span 1 / -1`. This way you explicitly say you want them to occupy a width equals the first column to the end of last one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that's if we know we want 3 columns. I'm asking about if we don't know how many cells there will be. Dynamic cell count with full width header and footer.

Comment: @BenRacicot Doesn't matter, it works for any number of cells/columns - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/rNVZNgp

Comment: @Paulie_D Ah, thanks for the pen, yes that shows the issue. The columns are defined by the grid algo and in that case there are 17 columns although only 9 cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not possible** in case of CSS Grids.

The CSS Grid will divide the columns according to the rules (if provided) or else it will automatically distribute the length/height to equally distribute in all columns/rows.

If you want to add a header and footer or some static blocks, it would be better if you wrap then in a different block.

And then in that different block you can create a new grid with new rules for header/footer according to your requirements.

IS it possible without JS?

**YES**, we only need CSS to have styling for grids.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, you begin by saying it's possible then end by saying it's not possible? The question is: Are a dynamic number of CSS Grid columns possible with optional header or footer row